# Angular-JS ng-repeat with asynchron data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've a store containing a lot of items. All of these items belongs to a category. So I have a function in my store to get all existing categories.

My code:
[http://plnkr.co/edit/rB4NMezhexEX4aFqveUO](http:///http://plnkr.co/edit/rB4NMezhexEX4aFqveUO)

But after loading the store, the $scope will be updated, but not the ng-repeat. What is the right Angular-Way to do this?

Regards
Bytecounter

Comment: your plunker link is dead !

Comment: @macrog: http://plnkr.co/edit/rB4NMezhexEX4aFqveUO

Comment: can you provide **working** plunkr? Also see errors in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

So i scrambled your code and I thing this is what u need:

js

```
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.products = [{name: 'Mercedes', type: "car"},
                     {name: 'Ford', type: "car"},
                     {name: 'BMW', type: "car"}];

  $scope.submitProduct = function () {
    $scope.products.push({name: 'Fiat', type: 'car'});
  };

}
```

html:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="product in products">
        {{product.name}}
      </div>
      <input type="button" ng-click="submitProduct()"  value="Click me">
  </div>
</div>
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/3459/

So ng-repeat list all objects in arrey, something happens (click action in my case) and that array changes, you just need to push it inside.

Hope it helps